# What's the name of the piece that holds the fender on (pic attached)

Tags: parts, fenders

What's the name of this part that holds the fender on?
(the back piece between that the rod from the fender is going through)

[image: Rear Derailleur area]

I've lost one but for the life of me can't seem to find what to search for.

Comment: also, the rod is called the *fender stay*

Comment: Relevant link to terminology index (just added): https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/88321/6852

Comment: The piece that holds the fender on in the attached picture is called a fender strut or fender brace, not a Rod. It's a metal bar that attaches to the fender and the frame of the bike to provide support and stability to the fender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A while ago I bought fenders from [Velo Orange](https://velo-orange.com/collections/fenders)<sup>no affiliation</sup> and on the product page  of their fenders they write:

> Hardware kit includes: 5mm polished aluminum stays, **R-clips** and screws, L bracket...

[image]

So to widen your search you can also look for "fender R-clip" in addition to "P clip"

Do note that not all P/R-clips are meant for the same fender stay diameter. Velo Orange uses 5mm stays for example, but other brands (e.g. Honjo) might use 4 mm. Best is to measure your stay diameter to select the correct clips.

The name "R Clip" or "P Clip" because they are shaped like an R or P when viewed from the side.

You may get away with a folded-over piece of metal, as long as it clamps down on the mudguard's stay.

Do consider adding thread locker - there's probably insufficient space for a locknut on the rear without hitting the chain.

[image]

Comment: It's worth noting that the VO struts are on the larger side in thickness. Honjo has the same thing in both 4mm and 5mm variants.

Comment: @NathanKnutson thanks for the addition, I didn't know. I have incorporated it in the answer.

Comment: I never knew there was such a thing as an R clip - makes sense to distinguish between something firmly clamping down on the shaft (we want this) vs something to just wrap-around and hold the item like a cable.